# Fetch from API and update state on other state change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, react-state

I am struggling to make an API request while using the `useEffect` hook.
This is my code:

```
  function ByConversationStatsTable({ id }) {
  const [start_time, set_start_time] = useState(new Date(0));
  const [end_time, set_end_time] = useState(new Date());
  const [num_of_sentences, set_num_of_sentences] = useState(2);

  const [data, set_data] = useState({
    scores: [],
    durations: [],
    avg_drop_count: "",
    top_N_failed_sentences: [],
    num_students_started: 0,
    num_students_finished: 0,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const res = await axios.get(
        `/api/v1/statistics/conversation/${id}?start_time=${start_time}&end_time=${end_time}&topFailedSentences=${num_of_sentences}`
      );
      set_data(res.data);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [start_time, end_time, num_of_sentences]);

  const {
    scores,
    durations,
    avg_drop_count,
    top_N_failed_sentences,
    num_students_started,
    num_students_finished,
  } = data;

  // round durations to nearest 5 seconds
  const durations_rounded = durations.map((dur) => Math.round(dur / 5) * 5);

  // const fetchData = props.fetchData;

  const updateStartTime = (new_start_time) => {
    const prev_time = start_time ? start_time.getTime() : -1;
    if (prev_time != new_start_time.getTime()) set_start_time(new_start_time);
  };

  const updateEndTime = (new_end_time) => {
    const prev_time = end_time ? end_time.getTime() : -1;
    if (prev_time != new_end_time.getTime()) set_end_time(new_end_time);
  };

  const [avg_sentences, total_sentences] = avg_drop_count.split("/");
  return (
    <div>
      <Row>
        <DatePicker
          datePickerType="range"
          onChange={(dates) => {
            if (dates.length === 2) {
              updateStartTime(dates[0]);
              updateEndTime(dates[1]);
            }
          }}
        >
          <DatePickerInput
            id="start_time"
            placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"
            labelText="Start date"
            size="md"
          />
          <DatePickerInput
            id="end_time"
            placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"
            labelText="End date"
            size="md"
          />
        </DatePicker>
        <NumberInput
          id="num_of_sentences"
          label="how many sentences"
          value={num_of_sentences}
          onChange={(e, { value, direction }) => set_num_of_sentences(value)}
        />
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Column>
          <GuageCustom
            part={avg_sentences}
            total={total_sentences}
            title={"Average drop sentence"}
            description={"Students fail at sentence $ out of $ on average"}
          />
        </Column>
        <Column>
          <GuageCustom
            part={num_students_finished}
            total={num_students_started}
            title={"Session Completion Rate"}
            description={"$ different students finished the lesson out of $"}
          />
        </Column>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Column>
          <Histogram
            data={scores}
            statName="Session Score"
            title="Session Scores"
          />
        </Column>
        <Column>
          <Histogram
            data={durations_rounded}
            statName="Session Duration"
            title="Session Durations (rounded to nearest 5 seconds)"
          />
        </Column>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <TopFailedKeywords data={top_N_failed_sentences} />
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Everything works fine when I use the date time picker to update `start_time` and `end_time` state members. But when I use the number input to update the `num_of_sentences` state member I get the following error

> Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.